# How do I create the URL to send a GET request for a form?

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, get, fetch-api

I am using this form.

```html
<form action="http://localhost:3000/">
  <input type="text"
    id="url"
    name="url"
    v-model="url"
    placeholder="http://">

  <input type="text" id="message" name="message" value="888">
  <button @click="submit" :disabled="disabled">Go</button>
</form>
```

Until now, pressing a button resulted in `http:localhost:300?url=...&message=...` page being fetched.

Now I am trying to manually override this, so I added `e.preventDefault();` to the `submit()` function. Now I can call Fetch API to fetch this URL manually, but how to I construct the URL from the form?

All online sources show how to do it with POST, no one seems to cover GET. Not sure why, because I need an idempotent request. Is there a standard way of doing this?

Comment: You're using Vue so why are you trying to handle this manually?

Comment: use `URL` and `URLSearchParams` to create the URL

Comment: Phil, good question. Because I am learning Vue right now. What's the Vue way?

Comment: @Bravo, `URLSearchParameters` will do, thank you. For a reference, here is a link: https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/transform-formdata-into-query-string  Unless there is a Vue way.

Comment: That's a point, didn't realise there was form handling goodness in vue -

Answer (score 2):

You're using Vue so typically you'd use something like this

```html
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="submit">
    <input
      type="text"
      v-model="url"
      placeholder="http://"
    />
    <input
      type="text"
      v-model="message"
    />
    <button type="submit" :disabled="disabled">Go</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

Notes:

- The `<button>` is a submit button without a *click* handler. This lets you listen for *submit* events on the `<form>` which can be triggered by mouse click *or* keyboard.
- The `@submit.prevent` handles the submit event on the `<form>` and prevents the default action automatically
- All `<input>` fields have an associated `v-model` backing a `data` property

Here's an example of the `<script>` part

```js
const target = "http://localhost:3000/";

export default {
  data: () => ({
    url: "",
    message: "888",
  }),
  computed: {
    // just an example
    disabled: ({ url, message }) => url.length === 0 || message.length === 0,
  },
  methods: {
    async submit() {
      const params = new URLSearchParams({
        url: this.url,
        message: this.message
      });
      const res = await fetch(`${target}?${params}`);
    },
  },
};
```

---

In regular JS, you can still listen for *submit* events on the form, capture all the fields using `FormData` and turn that into a query string with `URLSearchParams`

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const data = new FormData(e.target);
  const params = new URLSearchParams(data);
  const res = await fetch(`${e.target.action}?${params}`)
});
```